# How to return to previously nested `while True` loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

Say I have something in this kind of format:

```
while True1:
    if something:
        do some thing
    elif something else:
        do something else
        while True2:
            if something1:
                do some thing1
            if something2:
                do some thing2
            if want to end this while True2 loop
                go back to first while True1 loop
    elif something else else:
        do some thing else else
```

etc.

How can I make something within a `while True` loop go back to a previous `while True` loop that it was nested inside?

Comment: `break` will break out of the current loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `break` statement does just that.

```
while True: #1
    if something:
        do something
    elif something else:
        do something else
        while True: #2
            if something1:
                do something
            if something2:
                do something else
            if want to end this while True #2 loop:
                break            # will break out of the innermost loop only
    elif something else else:
        do some thing else else
```

Read more: [Control Flow Tools](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement.

```
x = 0
while True:
    x += 1
    if x == 5:
        print(x)
        break
```

will output `5` and exits